# Unity 2017 crashing when during Debug Step Over

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, crash, monodevelop, sigabrt

Using Unity 2017.4.

When I run a debug build the process stops at the breakpoint correctly.  However, regardless of the breakpoint location, as soon as I press 'Step Over' just once, Unity crashes.  This happens when using Visual Studio or MonoDevelop on my MacBook.

Here is the crash report.  Anyone know how to fix this?

```
Process:               Unity [10361]
Path:                  /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity
Identifier:            com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x
Version:               Unity version 2017.4.1f1 (2017.4.1f1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Unity [10361]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-04-23 21:52:42.170 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.2 (17C88)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        20D2D061-772F-2854-358E-8FF265CBA8E1

Sleep/Wake UUID:       2DDAD6D8-94F7-4D42-80BB-503704CCFC8D

Time Awake Since Boot: 44000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2200 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        64

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called



    Thread 0:: CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7baec7fe semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff7b97c82e _dispatch_sema4_wait + 16
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff7b974911 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 101
    3   com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x00000001025eb018 PlatformSemaphore::WaitForSignal() + 24
    4   com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x00000001025f3bae GfxDeviceClient::CreateGpuProgram(ShaderGpuProgramType, dynamic_array<unsigned char, 1ul> const&, CreateGpuProgramOutput&) + 382
    5   com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100df8378 ShaderLab::SubProgram::Compile() + 600
    6   com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100dceb17 GetSubProgramForShaderSnippet(Shader*, ShaderLab::Pass*, ShaderSnippet const&, ShaderType, unsigned int, ShaderKeywordSet const&, fixed_bitset<27, unsigned int> const&, dynamic_array<ShaderKeywordSet, 8ul> const*, ShaderCompilerPlatform, ShaderSnippetResult&, ShaderChannelMask&, ShaderRequirements) + 295
    7   com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100dfa1a9 ShaderLab::Program::CompileShaderSubProgram(Shader*, ShaderLab::Pass*, ShaderSnippet const&, unsigned int, ShaderKeywordSet&, ShaderSnippetResult&, ShaderChannelMask&, ShaderRequirements) + 601
    8   com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100dfa94c ShaderLab::Program::CompileMatchingSubProgram(Shader*, ShaderLab::Pass*, ShaderKeywordSet const&, unsigned int, ShaderKeywordSet*, ShaderSnippetResult&) + 1484
    9   com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100df7af9 ShaderLab::Program::GetMatchingSubProgram(Shader const*, ShaderLab::Pass const*, ShaderKeywordSet const&, unsigned int, ShaderKeywordSet*, ShaderSnippetResult&) const + 569
    10  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100df77b9 ShaderLab::Pass::ComputePassValuesHash(ShaderKeywordSet const&, ShaderPropertySheet const*, Shader*) const + 393
    11  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100d77d91 Material::UpdateHashes() + 305
    12  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100d77bf4 Material::BuildProperties() + 516
    13  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100d7ae7a Material::GetInstantiatedMaterial(Material*, Object&, bool) + 330
    14  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100a4f1d5 Renderer::GetAndAssignInstantiatedMaterial(int, bool) + 85
    15  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x000000010265105a Renderer_CUSTOM_GetMaterial(MonoObject*) + 186
    16  ???                             0x000000011fe93202 0 + 4830343682
    17  ???                             0x000000011fe930bf 0 + 4830343359
    18  ???                             0x000000011fe92da3 0 + 4830342563
    19  ???                             0x000000011e5657ea 0 + 4803942378
    20  libmono.0.dylib                 0x000000013770c08e 0x137702000 + 41102
    21  libmono.0.dylib                 0x00000001378389ca mono_runtime_invoke + 117
    22  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x000000010100ba9a ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool) + 106
    23  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x000000010100b97b ScriptingInvocation::InvokeChecked(ScriptingExceptionPtr*) + 59
    24  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100fbc5f8 MonoBehaviour::CallMethodInactive(ScriptingMethodPtr) + 344
    25  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100fc02b5 MonoBehaviour::CallAwake() + 101
    26  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100fc080a MonoBehaviour::AddToManager() + 282
    27  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x00000001010871ec AwakeFromLoadQueue::InvokePersistentManagerAwake(AwakeFromLoadQueue::Item*, unsigned int, AwakeFromLoadMode) + 380
    28  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100d3243f LoadSceneOperation::CompleteAwakeSequence() + 255
    29  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100d31ba2 LoadSceneOperation::PlayerLoadSceneFromThread() + 546
    30  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100d31712 LoadSceneOperation::IntegrateMainThread() + 802
    31  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100d337d6 PreloadManager::UpdatePreloadingSingleStep(PreloadManager::UpdatePreloadingFlags, int) + 470
    32  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100d341a2 PreloadManager::WaitForAllAsyncOperationsToComplete() + 114
    33  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x00000001012eb607 EditorSceneManager::RestoreSceneBackups(std::vector<EditorSceneManager::SceneBackup, stl_allocator<EditorSceneManager::SceneBackup, (MemLabelIdentifier)105, 16> >&, EditorSceneManager::PlayModeChange, bool) + 1815
    34  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x00000001019a7395 PlayerLoopController::EnterPlayMode(bool) + 533
    35  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x00000001019a21e6 PlayerLoopController::SetIsPlaying(bool) + 278
    36  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x00000001019a1a35 Application::TickTimer() + 4069
    37  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff562ad5b9 __NSFireTimer + 83
    38  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff5415fbb4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    39  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff5415f827 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1095
    40  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff5415f32a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 346
    41  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff5415692b __CFRunLoopRun + 2427
    42  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff54155d23 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
    43  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff5346de26 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
    44  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff5346da9f ReceiveNextEventCommon + 366
    45  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff5346d914 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
    46  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff51738f5f _DPSNextEvent + 2085
    47  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff51eceb4c -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
    48  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff5172dd6d -[NSApplication run] + 764
    49  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff516fcf1a NSApplicationMain + 804
    50  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x00000001006d3e07 EditorMain(int, char const**) + 839
    51  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x00000001006d4289 main + 9
    52  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff7b9a6115 start + 1

    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7baec7fe semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff7b97c82e _dispatch_sema4_wait + 16
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff7b974911 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 101
    3   com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x00000001025eb018 PlatformSemaphore::WaitForSignal() + 24
    4   com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100eecc06 profiling::Dispatcher::ThreadFunc(void*) + 70
    5   com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100e2783c Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) + 60
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc316c1 _pthread_body + 340
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc3156d _pthread_start + 377
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc30c5d thread_start + 13

    Thread 2:: com.apple.NSEventThread
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7baec7c2 mach_msg_trap + 10
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7baebcdc mach_msg + 60
    2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff54157355 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
    3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff541566a7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
    4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff54155d23 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
    5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff518763c8 _NSEventThread + 184
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc316c1 _pthread_body + 340
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc3156d _pthread_start + 377
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc30c5d thread_start + 13

    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7baf605a __semwait_signal + 10
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff7ba7175c nanosleep + 199
    2   com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100e2f5f2 ThreadHelper::SleepInSeconds(double) + 98
    3   com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100328ead CurlRequest::MessageThread() + 1565
    4   com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100328829 CurlRequest::_ThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 9
    5   com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000100e2783c Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) + 60
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc316c1 _pthread_body + 340
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc3156d _pthread_start + 377
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc30c5d thread_start + 13

    Thread 4:: NetworkConfigWatcher
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7baec7c2 mach_msg_trap + 10
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7baebcdc mach_msg + 60
    2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff54157355 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341
    3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff541566a7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783
    4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff54155d23 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
    5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff56235b76 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
    6   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000108511f84 0x10842f000 + 929668
    7   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x000000010851185c 0x10842f000 + 927836
    8   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000108566b46 0x10842f000 + 1276742
    9   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000108552b2d 0x10842f000 + 1194797
    10  org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x000000010857cb85 0x10842f000 + 1366917
    11  org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x000000010857865b 0x10842f000 + 1349211
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc316c1 _pthread_body + 340
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc3156d _pthread_start + 377
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc30c5d thread_start + 13

    Thread 5:: DnsConfigService
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7baf5fca __select + 10
    1   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000108710aa0 0x10842f000 + 3021472
    2   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000108589a1c 0x10842f000 + 1419804
    3   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x00000001085888bd 0x10842f000 + 1415357
    4   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000108510960 0x10842f000 + 924000
    5   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000108566b46 0x10842f000 + 1276742
    6   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000108552b2d 0x10842f000 + 1194797
    7   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x000000010857cb85 0x10842f000 + 1366917
    8   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x000000010857865b 0x10842f000 + 1349211
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc316c1 _pthread_body + 340
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc3156d _pthread_start + 377
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc30c5d thread_start + 13

    Thread 6:: WorkerPool/150579
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7baf5cee __psynch_cvwait + 10
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc3269b _pthread_cond_wait + 789
    2   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x00000001085740fb 0x10842f000 + 1331451
    3   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x000000010857f062 0x10842f000 + 1376354
    4   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x000000010857f5b0 0x10842f000 + 1377712
    5   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x000000010857865b 0x10842f000 + 1349211
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc316c1 _pthread_body + 340
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc3156d _pthread_start + 377
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc30c5d thread_start + 13

    Thread 7:: WorkerPool/210951
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7baf5cee __psynch_cvwait + 10
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc3269b _pthread_cond_wait + 789
    2   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x00000001085740fb 0x10842f000 + 1331451
    3   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x000000010857f062 0x10842f000 + 1376354
    4   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x000000010857f5b0 0x10842f000 + 1377712
    5   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x000000010857865b 0x10842f000 + 1349211
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc316c1 _pthread_body + 340
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc3156d _pthread_start + 377
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc30c5d thread_start + 13

    Thread 8:: OptimizingCompi
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7baec7fe semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    1   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000109a15e87 0x10842f000 + 22965895
    2   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x00000001099fab75 0x10842f000 + 22854517
    3   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000109b1a497 0x10842f000 + 24032407
    4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc316c1 _pthread_body + 340
    5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc3156d _pthread_start + 377
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc30c5d thread_start + 13

    Thread 9:: v8:SweeperThrea
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7baec7fe semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    1   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000109a15e87 0x10842f000 + 22965895
    2   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000109a93f17 0x10842f000 + 23482135
    3   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000109b1a497 0x10842f000 + 24032407
    4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc316c1 _pthread_body + 340
    5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc3156d _pthread_start + 377
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc30c5d thread_start + 13

    Thread 10:: v8:SweeperThrea
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7baec7fe semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    1   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000109a15e87 0x10842f000 + 22965895
    2   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000109a93f17 0x10842f000 + 23482135
    3   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000109b1a497 0x10842f000 + 24032407
    4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc316c1 _pthread_body + 340
    5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc3156d _pthread_start + 377
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc30c5d thread_start + 13

    Thread 11:: v8:SweeperThrea
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7baec7fe semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    1   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000109a15e87 0x10842f000 + 22965895
    2   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000109a93f17 0x10842f000 + 23482135
    3   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000109b1a497 0x10842f000 + 24032407
    4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc316c1 _pthread_body + 340
    5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc3156d _pthread_start + 377
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc30c5d thread_start + 13

    Thread 12:: Chrome_DBThread
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff7baf5cee __psynch_cvwait + 10
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc32662 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
    2   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000108574538 0x10842f000 + 1332536
    3   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x00000001085743e9 0x10842f000 + 1332201
    4   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000108556216 0x10842f000 + 1208854
    5   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000108566b46 0x10842f000 + 1276742
    6   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000108552b2d 0x10842f000 + 1194797
    7   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x0000000108f78188 0x10842f000 + 11833736
    8   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x000000010857cb85 0x10842f000 + 1366917
    9   org.chromium.ContentShell.framework 0x000000010857865b 0x10842f000 + 1349211
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc316c1 _pthread_body + 340
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc3156d _pthread_start + 377
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff7bc30c5d thread_start + 13

...

...

        0x7fff7bc48000 -     0x7fff7bc5bff7  libsystem_trace.dylib (829.30.14) <69EBF017-D40F-30D7-9B0B-BFC862D761A5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
        0x7fff7bc5d000 -     0x7fff7bc62ff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <6D4FCD49-D2A9-3233-95C7-A7635CE265F2> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
        0x7fff7bc63000 -     0x7fff7bc8fff7  libxpc.dylib (1205.30.29) <F7E5F1BC-614B-39CB-B6CE-92A9C7B7EC0B> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

    External Modification Summary:
      Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
        task_for_pid: 3
        thread_create: 0
        thread_set_state: 0
      Calls made by this process:
        task_for_pid: 0
        thread_create: 0
        thread_set_state: 0
      Calls made by all processes on this machine:
        task_for_pid: 23495
        thread_create: 0
        thread_set_state: 0

    VM Region Summary:
    ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=579.8M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=579.8M(100%)
    Writable regions: Total=1.2G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.2G(100%)

                                    VIRTUAL   REGION 
    REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
    ===========                     =======  ======= 
    Accelerate framework               384K        4 
    Activity Tracing                   256K        2 
    CG backing stores                 19.7M        4 
    CG image                            72K        5 
    CoreAnimation                       48K        8 
    CoreGraphics                         8K        2 
    CoreImage                           24K        3 
    CoreUI image data                 3088K       22 
    CoreUI image file                  180K        3 
    Foundation                           4K        2 
    IOKit                             7940K        2 
    Image IO                           256K        2 
    Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        2 
    MALLOC                           720.8M      138 
    MALLOC guard page                   64K       15 
    MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)           69.0M        8         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
    Memory Tag 242                      12K        2 
    Memory Tag 255                   547.5M       26 
    Memory Tag 255 (reserved)          140K        5         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
    OpenGL GLSL                        512K        7 
    STACK GUARD                       56.3M       86 
    Stack                            194.4M       87 
    VM_ALLOCATE                       87.1M      102 
    VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)           128.0M        3         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
    __DATA                            41.5M      317 
    __FONT_DATA                          4K        2 
    __GLSLBUILTINS                    2588K        2 
    __LINKEDIT                       236.4M       33 
    __TEXT                           343.5M      303 
    __UNICODE                          560K        2 
    mapped file                       94.0M      162 
    shared memory                     2848K       17 
    ===========                     =======  ======= 
    TOTAL                              2.5G     1346 
    TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     2.3G     1346 

    Model: MacBookPro12,1, BootROM MBP121.0171.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.9 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.28f7
    Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Built-In
    Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445364533303445452D45474346000000
    Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445364533303445452D45474346000000
    AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x133), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.5.1a3)
    Bluetooth: Version 6.0.2f2, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
    Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
    Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512G, 500.28 GB
    USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
    USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
    Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

Comment: This seems like a unity bug to me, have you posted it on their site yet?

Answer (score 1):

Find this path with terminal :

```
/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.Unity
```

-Then you will find a **subfolder** "MonoDevelop.Unity"

-You need move all the files and subfolders in **MonoDevelop.Unity/MonoDevelop.Unity** to the **first** **MonoDevelop.Unity** directory.

After all these steps,

-You can delete **2nd** MonoDevelop.Unity folder.

Hope this will help.